# How to create a search template with handlebars in ElasicSearch that is not json valid?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've looked at the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html#pre-registered-templates) but cannot get the following to work.

I have a search template that should look like this:

```
{
    "template": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "on_sale"
                        }
                    }
                    {{#size}}
                    ,
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "size": "{{size}}"
                        }
                    }
                    {{/#size}}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to register the stringified version of the template with the api i get the following:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search/template/test?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '"{\"template\": {\"query\": {\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"exists\": {\"field\": \"on_sale\"} } {{{#size}}} , {\"term\": {\"size\": \"{{size}}\"} } {{{/#size}}} ] } } } }"'

{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "not_x_content_exception",
        "reason" : "not_x_content_exception: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "not_x_content_exception",
    "reason" : "not_x_content_exception: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

**Update**

Tried removing the single quotes and changing content type to plain/text

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search/template/test?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -d "{\"template\": {\"query\": {\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"exists\": {\"field\": \"on_sale\"} } {{{#size}}}  {\"term\": {\"size\": \"{{size}}\"} } {{{/#size}}} ] } } } }"

{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "runtime_exception",
        "reason" : "runtime_exception: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@1ea516ee; line: 1, column: 78]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "runtime_exception",
    "reason" : "runtime_exception: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@1ea516ee; line: 1, column: 78]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "i_o_exception",
      "reason" : "Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@1ea516ee; line: 1, column: 78]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

Comment: You're not sending JSON data but plain text, try changing the content type to `text/plain` instead.

Comment: i get the same error...

Comment: Oh, you have a single quote + a double quote around your payload. Just remove the single quotes.

Comment: I updated the question with what you suggested and getting a new error. (The command after {{#size}} might be the problem. I guess it should only be present if 'size' is defined)

Comment: I meant to write "comma" instead of "command" i above comment